# Compatibility of ARC and Storyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, automatic-ref-counting

What's the compatibility of ARC and Storyboard considering devices and iOS?

Will ARC and Storyboard work on iPhone 3G, 3GS, 4 and 4S?

Will ARC and Storyboard work on iOS 4 and 5?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

ARC runs with 5.0 or higher, [Storyboard also needs iOS 5](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStoryboard_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Therefore, both are potentially available with the iPhone 3GS and above.

**EDIT:** Obviously, ARC is also compatible with iOS 4.0 and above, once you don't use `weak`. I briefly tested it, seems to work. That would mean that the iPhone 3G would also be compatible.

Comment: Thank's Phlibbo. Really helped!

Comment: The explanation on storybording is linked. Considering ARC, I'm afraid there is no official statement.

Comment: As a minor point, ARC is supported all the way back to iOS 4.0, not just 4.2. `weak` references should not be supported on iOS 4.3 either, just 5.0+.