# Does iOS 4.3 support ARC

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, automatic-ref-counting

I tried googling but i was unable to locate the Apples Documentation where they say that ARC - `automatic reference counting` supports for iOS 4.3. Can someone tell me if this is true ? if so can you post me a link to apples documentation where it says so.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7815128/compatibility-of-arc-and-storyboard

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xcode 4.2 with ARC: will my code run even on iOS devices with firmware older than 5.0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7768861/xcode-4-2-with-arc-will-my-code-run-even-on-ios-devices-with-firmware-older-tha)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Transitioning to ARC](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/_index.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226):

> ARC is supported in Xcode 4.2 for Mac OS X v10.6 and v10.7 (64-bit applications) and for iOS 4 and iOS 5. Weak references are not supported in Mac OS X v10.6 and iOS 4.

Comment: Because it doesn't represent any effort on my part.

Comment: is that's means that minimal iOS version = 4.0?

Answer (score -3):

Though ARC is in the new features list of [iOS 5](http://developer.apple.com/technologies/ios5/), apparently it is enabled by the compiler and that capability became 'switched on' for iOS 4 at the same time the updated compiler for iOS 5 was released.

I was provided this general clarification from Apple DTS. Cheers,

Comment: iOS 4.x does support ARC. iOS 3.x does not support ARC.