# iOS ARC enabled custom framework issue for iOS4.3

Tags: ios, frameworks, automatic-ref-counting

I have created a custom ios framework, which I intend to distribute without source.
Previously it was supposed to support devices with min iOS 5. But now it is decided to enable support from iOS 4.3

Now I face 2 primary issues.

1. My framework is ARC enabled.
   Can developers use the framework in ARC enabled / ARC disabled projects? How to use.
2. I use NSJSON
   As this is only available since iOS 5. I think I have to use something like JSON kit.
3. base sdk usage.
   Since I use ARC, if I decide to use baseSDK as 4.3, xCode will attach libarc along with my framework.

Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't have to worry about ARC. This is an implementation detail of your library. A client may use ARC or not.

Base SDK shall always be the most recent.

Deployment target is the lowest version you support: iOS 4.3

Regarding your JSON library, at any rate use `NSJSONSerialization` when *available*. You might check the version or better the class if it is available and then "branch" to the appropriate parser:

```
Class NSJSONSerializationClass = NSClassFromString(@"NSJSONSerialization");
NSError* error;
id jsonObject;
if (NSJSONSerializationClass == nil) {
    // No NSJSONSerialization class, use custom JSON parser:
    jsonObject = [MyJSONParser parseJSONData:data options:0 error:&error]; 
}
else {
    jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:error];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Arc is supported in iOS 4.3 [Arc Support 4.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8771791/does-ios-4-3-support-arc) regarding JSON, it might be best to use JSONKit as opposed to NSJSON for backwards compatibility.

Comment: How about developers who may want to include the framework in non-arc project ? Will it be a problem ? Remember the framework does not include the source in release.