# Is an iPhone / iPad app using a storyboard runs on iOS 4

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, storyboard

The file "storyboard" seems to be a novelty appeared with XCode 4 but in fact it is new in iOS 5.
My question is this: does a project iPhone / iPad created a storyboard not only work with earlier systems like iOS 4.3, 4.1, 4.0, 3 or even iPhone, 3G, etc.?

Thank you in advance

Comment: see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7815128/compatibility-of-arc-and-storyboard

Comment: What does ARC mean and stand for? In fact, I start developing with iPhone since xcode 4.3.2

Answer (score 4):

Storyboards are introduced in iOS 5 and there for can't be used on iOS 4 or lower.

Also the version of Xcode does reflect the version of the iOS SDK used. Nor dus the device version tell you any thing about the version of iOS it is running. (except you will no the max version it can run)

[`ARC`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html) is a new way to save the developer time on writing code, since you do not have to release object your self. The compiler will take care of this. `ARC` is support for any device running iOS 4.0 or higher.